# JsonPath DocumentContext update without updating the original object

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am trying to modify the JsonPath DocumentContext without modifying the original one, is that possible?

My Json structure

```
 {
    "header": {},
    "content": [
         "contentValue": {
                 "value": [ 
                   {}, 
                   {}
                  ]
         }
    ]
}   

DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
Object obj = JsonPath.read("$.content[0].contentValue.value[0]");
ctx.put("$.content[0]", "contentValue", obj);
```

This code modify the original ctx which I dont want to do. Any direction on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you cannot alter the context at all, its final. And cloning the object to another object seems really tedious so in the end I formed a new object with the params I needed.